# difference between sets of ordered categorical variables

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, survey, ordinal-data, distance-functions

I have two sets (S1, S2) of answers to a typical survey question with ordered categorical (discrete) answers (“strongly disagree”, “disagree”, … ,” strongly agree”). I need to test whether I should reject the null-hypothesis that S1 and S2 come from the same distribution.

Because the categories are ordered, a chi2 test is not suitable. Because the answers are discrete a traditional KS test is also not suitable. I am aware of KS tests for discrete variables, but they seem weak on the computation of the significance level (maybe I have not found the good papers). I am considering the following approach. Call C1 and C2 the cumulative density function of S1 and S2.

1. Compute the KS distance between C1 and C2
2. Use permutation test (by shuffling S1 and S2) to test the statistical significance at point 2

Do you have any comment? Will this do?

Comment: Consider the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model, which tests the same thing as the WIlcoxon test but handles ties better.  Details may be found in [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms) but a gentler introduction may be found in [BBR course notes](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. I am probably a little slow on this, but how would i use this regression model to test whether the two data sets come from the same distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinal (semiparametric) models do not assume any reference distribution (e.g., the S1 population distribution) but assume that under a certain transformation (e.g., logit for proportional odds/Wilcoxon test) the S2 distribution is a vertical shift of the S1 distribution.  E.g. the proportional odds model assumes that the cumulative distribution functions of logit(S1) and logit(S2) are parallel.  Under that assumption you would be testing for equality of whole distributions.  This can be reworded as testing for the tendency for observations from S2 to be larger than those from S1.  The test will not test all possible distribution differences, just as the two-sample t-test will not detect differences in variances when the means are equal.

Comment: thank you for the additional explanation

Comment: On this site thanks is expressed by upvoting.  But thanks though.